# Thresholding output from semantic segmentaiton?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am segmenting microscopy images using a model I built with a UNet architecture. I get reasonable results after training my model, so I know it's working. As outputs, I obtain arrays with predicted values between 0 and 1. On one hand this makes sense because I'm employing a sigmoid activation function (which should produce output between 0 and 1). However, ideally each value would be 0 or 1 as it is in my target image. I'm wondering if I should add a threshold step after my sigmoid activation in the model to make each value 0 or 1 so that this is the value used to train the model. I'm not sure if this is something people do, and I was hoping to get some insight.

Here's an example of what I get. I thresholded my output after the fact:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to introduce a threshold value into the sigmoid function, but this approach is seldom used to enhance segmentation accuracy.

There are various methods available to improve model accuracy:

1. Employing DICE loss: This approach directly utilizes the DICE coefficient as the learning function for the segmentation model [1].
2. Utilizing StarDist: StarDist is a modified version of U-Net that performs well, particularly in cell segmentation tasks [2].

[image]

3. Post-processing: You can apply erosion and dilation to smooth the cell boundaries. The skimage Python module offers these functions.

**Reference:**

[1] Milletari, F., Navab, N., & Ahmadi, S. A. (2016, October). V-net: Fully convolutional neural networks for volumetric medical image segmentation. In *2016 fourth international conference on 3D vision (3DV)* (pp. 565-571). Ieee.

[2] Schmidt, U., Weigert, M., Broaddus, C., & Myers, G. (2018). Cell detection with star-convex polygons. In Medical Image Computing and Computer Assisted Intervention–MICCAI 2018: 21st International Conference, Granada, Spain, September 16-20, 2018, Proceedings, Part II 11 (pp. 265-273). Springer International Publishing.